# How to make friends bonobo git server and SourceTree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, bonobo

How to make friends bonobo git server and SourceTree?
I installed Bonobo git server (6.5.0), by default.
Added user.
When trying to connect SourceTree, an error occurs:

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

1. Control Panel->Credential Manager (search, depends on your version of windows)
2. Windows Crentials
3. Add a generic credential
4. git:http://yourbonoboserver.info
5. user and password credentials to connect to your server

[https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/In-V-2-x-Where-does-source-tree-store-the-accounts-saved/qaq-p/593158#:~:text=1%20answer&text=The%20credentials%20are%20stored%20in,Windows%20which%20SourceTree%20interacts%20with](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/In-V-2-x-Where-does-source-tree-store-the-accounts-saved/qaq-p/593158#:%7E:text=1%20answer&text=The%20credentials%20are%20stored%20in,Windows%20which%20SourceTree%20interacts%20with).